# Folders can not be found after converting a JAVA project into a runnable JAR

Tags: java, jar, directory, runnable, getresource

I hope somebody can help me with my problem. After hours of scanning all different posts concerning the abovementioned topic I now decided to answer my own question. None of the other posts solved my problem.

I want to export an existing JAVA project as runnable JAR. Therefore I'm changing all absolute references to the following:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/somekindofimage.png").toString();
```

This way I can reach all available files in the runnable JAR.

However I need to reference a folder...so I tried it the same way:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/somekindoffolder").toString();
```

which gives me the following path:

```
file:\C:\Users\...\1_data_collection
```

By creating a file and checking with "is.Directory" it returns false.
I unzipped the runnable JAR. All folders, all files that are needed are included. They are attached as sources via BuildPath.

When I test the abovementioned path with Windows Explorer it directs me to the folder I'm looking for.

I'm using Eclipse Neon 2 as IDE, my JAVA Version is 1.8-0_144.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply put, you can’t.  There are no folders inside a .jar file.  A .jar file is actually a zip file, which is just a list of entries with string names that happen to look like file paths.  There is no way to “list” files in a “folder.”  But since you are the one building your .jar, you know exactly which files you’re putting in it, so you *can* make a simple text file that lists those files, and have your application read that text file.

Comment: Actually there are folders in the JAR when I unpack the archiv. As I mentioned all resources that I need are available. I don't want to list the files...I just want to get the references of the folders..to provide it to a plugin I want to use.

Comment: Class.getResource returns a URL, not a file name.  So if you convert it to a string, you won’t have a valid file path.  There is, in fact, no way to reliably convert that URL to a valid file path, because an entry in a .jar isn’t a file, it’s just subsequence of bytes.  If some API needs a folder, you need to create a folder and copy your bundled items into it.  [Files.createTempDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) is useful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to files in a JAR using a File path.  You have to load them as resources from the classpath.

Make sure the resources and dependencies you need are packaged in the JAR.  There's a Maven Shade plugin, if you're using Maven, that will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - as I mentioned, all folders and files are included in the JAR as they are configured as source folders in the Build Path. So the question is how do I access them, or do you mean that it should be possible in the way I mentioned?

Comment: It's not possible the way you did it. Your code already told you that.  You need to access files as stream resources from your JAR classpath.  Make sure there's a proper manifest file to set the classpath properly, too.